# Angular animations: WebKit support

Tags: angular, angular-animations

Is there a way to use -webkit keyframes in Angular animations?
I have defined a blur trigger like this:

```
export const blurAnimation =

trigger('blur', [
  transition('1 => 0', [
    animate('500ms ease-in', keyframes([

      style({
        filter: 'blur(5px)',
        // webkitFilter: 'blur(5px)' // NOT WORKING
      }),

      style({
        filter: 'blur(0)',
        // WebkitFilter: 'blur(0)' // NOT WORKING
    })
  ]))
])
```

The simple blur works, but Safari needs --webkit-filter.

Answer (score 0):

Install web animations as

```
npm install 'web-animations-js'
```

Then add to polyfills.ts:

```
import 'web-animations-js';
```

Angular animations guide mentions that

> For other browsers, a polyfill is required. Grab web-animations.min.js
>   from here and add it to your page

you don't need to add webkitfilter in code, filter should work fine with web animations.

For more information you can read https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10420